# Custom typecasting

Tags: swift, types, casting, swift2

How can one implement a custom typecast in Swift?

It seems that `as` is an operator that can have a custom implementation on a class but I cannot find any documentation on it.

An example of a use case: one may wish to cast from the Swift `String` type to a custom class like `UCS4String`, which implements its own methods and internal representation.

If `as` cannot be used for this purpose though, what is the preferred pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast something only to something that it might actually be. For example, you can cast a class down to a subclass. (For example, if a view is a UIImageView but your reference to it starts out as a UIView reference, you can cast it down to a UIImageView with the `as!` operator.) But String is not a class, so it cannot be downcast in that way.

Similarly, you cannot cast between numeric types: for example, you cannot cast Int to UInt or vice versa.

Instead, you need to supply your type with an *initializer* so that you can *coerce* to an instance of your type based on the old instance. That's how you get a UInt from an Int:

```
let i2 = UInt(i)
```

And so in your case:

```
let s2 = UCS4String(string:s)
```

Comment: still let str:String = "swiftstring" let nstr = str as NString works fine. i think that the question is "can we override the as operator?"

Comment: But my answer answered that. Behind the scenes, String and NSString are the same type, so the cast is possible. @user3441734

Comment: there are the same behind the scenes ???? hm ... i disagree. i can be wrong, but i am pretty sure that native String and Foundation NSString class are different by the nature. casting operators are defined in standard swift library, may be now, when opensource swift is available, we can check the sources ... so or so, nowadays we can not overload the casting operators.

Comment: @user3441734 You can be "pretty sure" of whatever you like. But they _are_ the same nonetheless. The cast changes nothing about the underlying storage. That's why the cast is possible. They are _bridged_. You might want to read my book: Casting: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_casting Bridging: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_objects_and_swift_objects

Comment: String is bridged to Objective-C as NSString, and a String that originated in Objective-C MAY store its characters in an NSString. Since any arbitrary subclass of NSSString can become a String, there are NO GUARANTEES ABOUT REPRESENTATION or efficiency in this case.